# One woocommerce store across 3 wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an english WP site with its store(main), and i will implement a bulgarian and romanian version. Can i keep my main store and use it to my others sites?

Something like:

```
main domain www.abc.com
2nd site: www.ro.abc.com
3nd site: www.bg.abc.com
```